# Android View, What is this?

Tags: android, view

What do you call this view? I really want to use it with my database. I just want to click the button that says uses. and then it will display the content from my database to the textview.

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4112/6nus232s_png.htm

Comment: the image is not clear

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Could be a number of things. Such as ExpandableListView or a customer RecyclerView. You could use either to achieve that kind of result. I sure you can find plenty of examples of it with ExpandableListView.

Comment: We call it `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Image is not so clear But I think you want to show user, the data in the Form of Expendable list view 
[image]

if this is what you want consider following link 
You can read more about [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) here

and [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/) it is a nice tutorial

Comment: Yup, its like that, but when you click it, it shows a textview. I really don't know what it is, it has a very wide spacing between them? maybe they used many expandable listviews?

Comment: what are you trying to say ? Have you implemented it ?

Comment: Nope, not yet, nvm i said that,  i just saw an app that has it. i'll try implementing it using the link you gave. :)

Comment: I think then You should mark this as accepted answer because what was the context of your question , this answer fulfills that.